# WPF: Strategy for Creating a Single Item Paged ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, custom-controls, itemscontrol

I am wanting to build a WPF custom control that displays validation errors - one at a time - in a ribbon that goes across the top of the screen.

An ItemsControl or Selector sounds like a potential base class candidate, but my requirement is that only one item is shown at a time and the user will click on forward and back buttons on the ribbon to navigate through the validation errors.

Is it possible to use an ItemsControl in this way? To only show one item at a time?

Is there a better strategy for this?

I appreciate your thoughts and expertise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/741026/WPF-FlipView) article should cover everything you want to do. The FlipView basically behaves like an ItemsControl and shows one item at a time by providing forward/back buttons.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction on the design of my control. While I am not going to use a FlipView, I realized that an ItemsControl would not be appropriate for my design.